# Access layer attribute in custom loss function in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to write a custom loss function in Keras which depends on an attribute of a (custom) layer in the network.

The idea is the following:

- I have a custom layer which modifies the input in each epoch based on a random variable
- The output labels should be modified based on the same variable

Some example code to make it more clear:

```py
import numpy as np
from keras import losses, layers, models

class MyLayer(layers.Layer):
    def call(self, x):
        a = np.random.rand()
        self.a = a # <-- does this work as expected?
        return x+a

def my_loss(layer):
    def modified_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        a = layer.a
        y_true = y_true + a
        return losses.mse(y_true, y_pred)

input_layer = layers.Input()
my_layer = MyLayer(input_layer, name="my_layer")
output_layer = layers.Dense(4)(my_layer)
model = models.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)
model.compile('adam', my_loss(model.get_layer("my_layer")))
```

I expect that `a` is changing for every batch and that the same `a` is used in the layer and loss function.
Right now, it is not working the way I intended. It seems like the `a` in the loss function is never updated (and maybe not even in the layer).

How do I change the attribute/value of `a` in the layer at every call and access it in the loss function?

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure I am following the purpose on this (and I am bothered by the call to `np` inside the `call()` of your custom layer - could you not use the `tf.random` functions instead?) but you can certainly access the `a` property inside your loss function.

Perhaps something like:

```py
class MyLayer(layers.Layer):
    def call(self, x):
        a = np.random.rand() # FIXME --> use tf.random
        self.a = a
        return x+a

input_layer = layers.Input()
my_layer = MyLayer(input_layer, name="my_layer")
output_layer = layers.Dense(4)(my_layer)
model = models.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=output_layer)

def my_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  y_true = y_true + my_layer.a
  return losses.mse(y_true, y_pred)


model.compile('adam', loss=my_loss)
```